# Changing DOM element type depending on AngularJS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

What I am trying to achieve is depending on a scope variable the DOM element will change type..

So say I have a scope var like:

```
$scope.post = {
    title:          'Post title goes here!',
    slug:           'post-title-goes-here',
    category:       'News',
    featured_image: '//src.jpg'
};
```

And a DOM element like:

```
<a href="#/post/{{post.slug}}">
    <div style="background-image: url({{post.featured_image}});">
        <small ng-if="post.category">{{post.category}}</small>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    </div>
</a>
```

But if the var `$scope.post.slug` was empty the DOM element would look like:

```
<div>
    <div style="background-image: url({{post.featured_image}});">
        <small ng-if="post.category">{{post.category}}</small>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I can do an `ng-if` and duplicate each bit of code but I'm trying to avoid that!

Something like this would be ideal:

```
<{{post.slug ? 'a href="#/post/'+post.slug+'"' : 'div'}}>
    <div style="background-image: url({{post.featured_image}});">
        <small ng-if="post.category">{{post.category}}</small>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    </div>
</{{post.slug ? 'a' : 'div'}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this directly with angular. HTML needs to be defined before angular injects. But for this case I think is a better option to control the anchor with a function in your controller's logic. Just set your DOM with a div and a **ng-click='yourFunction()'** and in case post.slug exists do the navigation with your **angular's routing system**.

Answer (score 0):

A custom directive will allow you to do the ng-if's to determine `<a>` tag or `<div>` tag without polluting your view. ngTransclude in the directive includes your content.

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <div slug-link="post.slug">
        <div style="background-image: url({{post.featured_image}});">
            <small ng-if="post.category">{{post.category}}</small>
            <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('slugLink', function()
{
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      slug: '=slugLink'
    },
    template: '<a ng-href="{{slug}}" ng-if="slug" ng-transclude></a><div ng-if="slug == \'\'" ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

See full source in the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnVUV8tHO8YoGrcujWKE)

Comment: You're right. Fixed and updated that. I was messing around with a couple different ways to do that check. The OP can edit those values to match the data he has.